# AWS Route53 redirect mywebsite.net to mywebsite.com

Tags: dns, amazon-route53

All I want to do is point the root

```
mywebsite.net -> mywebsite.com
```

I can do `CNAME`

```
www.mywebsite.net -> www.mywebsite.com
```

but can not create and `Alias`

```
mywebsite.net -> www.mywebsite.net
```

Right now I have to point the `mywebsite.net` to the same `ELB` as `mywebsite.com` but if I change the `ELB` then I have to update in 2 places.

Is there any way to point the `.net` to `.com` directly from Route53?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is an issue with the [rules of DNS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034), which forbid a CNAME record where another record exists.

> If a CNAME RR is present at a node, no other data should be
> present; this ensures that the data for a canonical name and its aliases
> cannot be different.  This rule also insures that a cached CNAME can be
> used without checking with an authoritative server for other RR types.

Because you have NS, and SOA records at the @ record, you can't have a CNAME.

So it is perfectly ok to have

```
www.example.com -> CNAME -> example.org
www.example.com -> CNAME -> www.example.org
```

The only way to solve your problem is to create a duplicate A record at the root of `mywebsite.net`

```
example.com -> 12.34.56.78
example.org -> 12.34.56.78
```

There are also a few DNS providers who allow a special type of CNAME record, sometimes refered to as an ANAME, which is a type of CNAME they use at the root of a domain.

A possible solution for Route 53 might be to do something like this

```
org.example.com > CNAME > example.org
example.org > ANAME > org.example.com
```

Edited to address comments -

If you have multiple domains that need to be periodically updated. This is probably not something that DNS is well suited to keeping track of.

Personally I would create a small [lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/lambda/) script that you could either run when required to check a single domain name and update the other records whenever it changed.

This is a much better fit for automation than for DNS. Have a script that you can run everytime you need updates, it will make the thing a whole lot less complex and / or error prone.

Comment: Specifically here, though, the issue here is with Route 53, which supports Alias ("aname") records, but not across zones -- only within zones, or when pointing to AWS-provided endpoints from services like ELB, S3, CloudFront, and EB.

Comment: For the workaround, I'd suggest static redirects using empty S3 buckets with the web site hosting feature, to send the bare domain to the www site using `301` redirects, with aliases in the bare domain sending them to S3... then one www can be a cname pointing to the other -- solved. :)  Or CloudFront+S3 redirect if SSL is needed for the redirect.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot i checked the guide using empty S3 bucket. But in my case since I already have ELB and CloudFront so I only have to point the root domain to ELB/CloudFront domain. Route53 supports CNAME Alias and it works well. The thing is I have to manage 10 countries domain like .hk, .tw, .sg, etc so in the future when I switch the ELB then I have to do the update in multiple zones.

Comment: @MichaelB i also tried `example.org > ANAME > org.example.com` but Route53 does not allow that, it only said `Alias Target contains an invalid value.`